# Get cache location with env variable

Tags: npm, npm-cache

I get get the NPM cache location using:

```
  cache_location="$(npm get cache)"
```

however, is this value also represented by an env variable that I can read?

Something like `NPM_CACHE_LOCATION`?

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** It depends on when/how you want to access it, as there is no env variable, (e.g. `NPM_CACHE_LOCATION`), available whilst npm is *not* running.

You'll need to invoke `npm config get cache` or `npm get cache` as you are currently doing.

However, once npm is running the configuration parameters are put into the environment with the `npm_` prefix.

The following demonstrates this...

---

#### Discover which env variables are available:

As a way to find out what env variable(s) npm puts in the environment, you can utilize [printenv](https://ss64.com/bash/printenv.html) in an npm-script. For example in *package.json* add:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "print-env-vars": "printenv | grep \"^npm_\""
},
...
```

Then run the following command:

```
npm run print-env-vars
```

#### Get the cache location via an env variable:

In the resultant log to the console, (i.e. after running `npm run print-env-vars`), you'll see that there's the `npm_config_cache` environment variable listed. It reads something like this:

```
npm_config_cache=/Users/UserName/.npm
```

In the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#configuration) it states:

> **configuration**
>
> Configuration parameters are put in the environment with the **`npm_config_`** prefix. For instance, you can view the effective **`root`** config by checking the **`npm_config_root`** environment variable.

Note: Running `printenv | grep "^npm_"` directly via the CLI returns nothing.

#### Accessing the cache location with env variable:

1. You can access the cache location via an npm-script, For example:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "cache-loc-using-bash": "echo $npm_config_cache",
     "cache-loc-using-win": "echo %npm_config_cache%"
   },
   ```

   See [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) for utilizing a cross-platforms syntax.
2. Accessing the npm cache location via a *Nodejs* script. For example:

   ```js
   const cacheLocation = process.env.npm_config_cache;
   console.log(cacheLocation)
   ```

   *Note:* This node script will need to be invoked via an npm-script for the `process.env.npm_config_cache` to be available. Invoking it via the command line running, e.g. `node ./somefile.js` will return `undefined` - this further demonstrates that the parameters with the `_npm` prefix are only put into the environment whilst npm is running.

---

Not ideal, however you could set your own environment variable using [export](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html) of course:

```
export NPM_CACHE_LOCATION="$(npm get cache)"
```

and [unset](https://ss64.com/bash/unset.html) to remove it:

```
unset NPM_CACHE_LOCATION
```